# Random False Positives on SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using sonarqube v6.7 and have SonarJava 4.15.0.12310 installed.

When I analyse one of my projects, I get **18 New Critical and 15 New Major Issues** (These issues are false positives) these issues are reduced to **1 New Major Issue** (different from the previous and also false positives) when I mark the previous as "False Positive or Won't Fix"

Also on marking the **1 New Major Issue** as "False Positive or Won't Fix", the previous **18 New Critical and 15 New Major Issues** comes up again and the loop continues infinitely.

Please any ideas on how to resolve this

**NOTE:** I have cleared the cache and it has been like this for some couple of weeks

Comment: At what point in the cycle are these issues reintroduced? After a subsequent analysis, or before?

Comment: Thanks for the response. They are reintroduced after subsequent analysis. Also the affected files are were not changed within the leak period

Comment: That would be awesome if you could provide a small reproducer. Like sharing the offending file content + the rule keys of the reported issues.

Comment: these are the rule keys (squid:S1948, squid:S1948, squid:S1244, squid:S1161, squid:S2159, squid:S1172, squid:S2178)